# Spring 3.1+ argument resolver cannot handle proprietary Person class argument

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I just upgraded from Spring 3.0 to 3.2. I've configured a custom argument resolver like this in my spring configuration xml file:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
  <mvc:argument-resolvers>
    <bean class="mycompany.api.PersonResolver" />   
  </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

My Spring MVC controller has a method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/api/doSomething", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody JsonNode handleRestCall(Person person) {
  ...
  return jsonNode;
}
```

Where the Person class is our own proprietary class.

However, this does NOT work. It gives me an error:

```
Rest call error argument type mismatch
HandlerMethod details: 
    Controller [MyController]
    ...
    Resolved arguments: 
    [0] [type=org.springframework.validation.support.BindingAwareModelMap] [value=    {org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.objectNode=org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 0 errors}]

    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

It appears that changing my Person argument type to some other type (in my case: PersonWrapper, containing a reference to a Person) offers me a workaround for the problem, i.e. Spring can now resolve the argument.

Can someone explain this to me? Is this because Spring uses java Reflection and has some name clash with some Spring Person class (Spring security has a org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.Person class) ?

Implementation of my resolver:
My initial implementation looked like:

```
import mycompany.Person;

public class PersonResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver  {
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter mp) {
      return mp.getParameterType().equals(Person.class);
}

    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter mp, ModelAndViewContainer mavc, NativeWebRequest nwr, WebDataBinderFactory wdbf) throws Exception {
      if(mp.getParameterType().equals(Person.class)) {
        ...
        return somePerson;
      }
      return UNRESOLVED;
    }
}
```

Spring configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config /> 

    <!-- automatically search for Controller classes using @Controller annotation -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="mycompany.api"/>

    <!-- we use Spring 3 annotation driven development -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:argument-resolvers>
                <bean class="mycompany.api.PersonResolver" />   
                <bean class="mycompany.api.SessionLocaleResolver"/>
        </mvc:argument-resolvers>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

</beans>
```

Comment: It shouldn't cause any issues with name clashes because that's what packages were invented. Can you show us the `PersonResolver` implementation too?

Comment: Can you post your full configuration for the `DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: Please put a log statement in your `PersonResolver` initialization code to help determine if it's actually getting loaded. If your example is accurate, the package names in your XML Beans file and your actual class don't match.

Comment: I added a default constructor in my Resolver class with logging. It IS called on startup. 
When I use my workaround wrapper class, it also calls the supportsParameter method, but for my Person argument it doesn't even call this method...

Comment: I found out now that our Person class implements the Map<String,String> interface, which causes the problem. When I try to resolve an argument implementing the map interface, it fails!
Apparently, Spring MVC tries to resolve it before our own resolver gets the chance.

Comment: Correct, spring first consults a list of its own resolvers, then the custom and finally a couple of fallback resolvers and for a Map there is the `MapMethodProcessor` which handles this. (Which is invoked before the custom converters).

Comment: Can these fallback (built-in) resolvers be configured to skip some arguments or can a priority be set (so the PersonResolver comes first)?

Comment: No... The only way to override/change the order is to create a `BeanPostProcessor` and add your `PersonResolver` to the top of the list (instead of using the namespace to configure the resolver).